# VBA .navigate going straight to download

Tags: vba

I have a simple problem, I think. I would like to view a png by going straight to a http link.

Problem is, I keep going straight to the downloads.

I'm betting this is just a matter of flipping a switch somewhere.

```
Sub CamelGraph() 'ASIN As String

    Dim ASIN As String
    ASIN = "0395967392"


    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Dim URL As String
    URL = "https://charts.camelcamelcamel.com/us/" & ASIN & "/sales-rank.png?force=1&zero=0&w=725&h=440&legend=1&ilt=1&tp=1y&fo=0&lang=en"


    ie.Visible = True
    apiShowWindow ie.hwnd, sw_maximize
    ie.navigate URL

End Sub
```

Comment: Please check URL parameters after question mark. One of them may cause file to download rather than display on website. If there was "dl" parameter, I would be sure. Maybe "force=1" as 'force download' = true? You could start by removing all parameters and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has more to do with Browser types (i.e. IE vs. Chrome), and the MIME types being used. While you could potentially fix this on individual computers or with workarounds (like Chrome Redirector), maybe consider downloading the file, and then opening it with a Shell command? I know this is not perfect, but I do think it would offer more consistent results on different machines.

Here is some VBA code to download a file, and then you can just Shell to it to open it with the default associated application:

```
Sub DownloadFile()

Dim myURL As String
myURL = "https://YourWebSite.com/?your_query_parameters"

Dim WinHttpReq As Object
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False, "username", "password"
WinHttpReq.send

myURL = WinHttpReq.responseBody
If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile "C:\file.csv", 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
    oStream.Close
End If

End Sub
```

Good luck, Jason!

Answer (score 0):

Try to navigate to a blank page `.Navigate "about:blank"` first to display the image in browser window.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "about:blank"
        Do While .readyState <> 4 Or .Busy
            DoEvents
        Loop
        .Navigate "https://charts.camelcamelcamel.com/us/0395967392/sales-rank.png?force=1&zero=0&w=725&h=440&legend=1&ilt=1&tp=1y&fo=0&lang=en"
        Do While .readyState <> 4 Or .Busy
            DoEvents
        Loop
        Do While .Document.readyState <> "complete"
            DoEvents
        Loop
    End With

End Sub
```